# wp_mail() filter wp_mail_from not working

Tags: wordpress, email, filter

I built a small function to send contact form results and bug reports.

I ask the user to enter name and email and I want to use that email address to appear in mail I'm getting.

I'm using the wp_mail filter for this:

`add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from', $gotten_mail );
function my_mail_from( $email )
{
    return $email;
}`

It's not working.

I'm thinking maybe to change smtp address instead of using this filter.
searching how.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone had same problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Realize this is over a month old, but here goes...

You can't add your custom parameters into your `add_filter` call that way. Instead, you will need to grab the entered email in your callback function, like so:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'custom_slug_mail_from' );

/**
 * Function to change mail_from to input entered via form.
 */
function custom_slug_mail_from( $email ) {

    /**
     * Use the user-submitted email if present.
     */
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'email_from_form' ] ) )
        return sanitize_email( $_REQUEST[ 'email_from_form' ] );

    return $email; // if no email submitted, use default.
}
```

Haven't tested this, but I think it should work. Be sure to change 'custom_slug' to the name of your theme or plugin folder per the WordPress [Theme Guidelines](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review#Code_Quality%3a) and change 'email_from_form' to be the name of the input field from your form.

P.S. You'll get WordPress-related answers faster at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try and give you a feedback.

Comment: @MichaelDozark +1 for answering an old question :)